# SVG 'color' property not taking precedence over generic CSS 'color' property

Tags: html, css, svg

```css
:root {
  --logo-color: red;
  --text-color: blue;
}

* {
  color: var(--text-color)
}

.logo{
  color: var(--logo-color);
}
```

```html
<svg
 class="logo"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="24"
 height="24"
 viewBox="0 0 24 24"
 fill="none"
 stroke="currentColor"
 stroke-width="2"
 stroke-linecap="round"
 stroke-linejoin="round"
>
   <circle cx="12" cy="5" r="3" />
   <line x1="12" y1="22" x2="12" y2="8" />
   <path d="M5 12H2a10 10 0 0 0 20 0h-3" />
</svg>
```

I attempted to modify the color of an SVG using the `color` property in my CSS file. I selected the `.logo` class and anticipated the logo to appear in red. However, it ended up being displayed in blue, as if the generic CSS (0-0-0) had higher precedence than the class-specific styles (0-1-0). And if I remove the `color` property from the generic block, then it works normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Beware asterisk (`*`)

The culprit in your code is that even though `*` has the weakest specificity, it actually **matches everything**, not only the `svg` element (that by itself does not "draw" anything), but also all its **descendants** (that do the actual drawing). So basically your explicit

```
svg  { color: red; }
```

has no effect, because its children (**`circle`, `line` and `path`**) elements are all then again matched by the preceding

```
* { color: blue; }
```

so the `color: red` that would otherwise be inherited from the parent is there overridden to `blue` from `*`.  In a simplified sample:

```css
* {
  color: blue;
}

svg {
  color: red;
}

html { color-scheme: light dark; }
```

```html
<svg
 width="24"
 height="24"
 viewBox="0 0 24 24"
 fill="none"
 stroke="currentColor"
 stroke-width="2"
 stroke-linecap="round"
 stroke-linejoin="round"
>
   <circle cx="12" cy="5" r="3" />
   <line x1="12" y1="22" x2="12" y2="8" />
   <path d="M5 12H2a10 10 0 0 0 20 0h-3" />
</svg>
```

#### How to fix - even more force

There are several ways how to cope with this. One could be overriding general child selector in the more specific selector: `svg *` (`.logo *`) into your CSS

```css
* {
  color: blue;
}

svg * {
  color: red;
}

html { color-scheme: light dark; }
```

```html
<svg
 width="24"
 height="24"
 viewBox="0 0 24 24"
 fill="none"
 stroke="currentColor"
 stroke-width="2"
 stroke-linecap="round"
 stroke-linejoin="round"
>
   <circle cx="12" cy="5" r="3" />
   <line x1="12" y1="22" x2="12" y2="8" />
   <path d="M5 12H2a10 10 0 0 0 20 0h-3" />
</svg>
```

---

#### Why it works

Fact that CSS `color` property affects your strokes is indeed set by SVG's root node `stroke="currentColor"` attribute, that makes SVG *and all its children* copy the computed `color` value into `stroke` (unless explicitly told otherwise). It is usually a good practice to do this and not copy colour values to `stroke` and/or `fill`.

#### Best practice (in general)

Best practice would probably be **not using `*`** at all and let implicit `color` value **inheritance** do its work:

```css
html {
 background-color: darkslategray;
 color: tan;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

/*
Just for brevity.
It is always better to keep SVG presentational attributes in the document
rather than in CSS; *especially* dimensions and fills/strokes.
*/
svg {
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 fill: none;
 stroke: currentColor;
 stroke-width: 2;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

```html
<p>Text with
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="anchor">
   <circle cx="12" cy="5" r="3" />
   <line x1="12" y1="22" x2="12" y2="8" />
   <path d="M5 12H2a10 10 0 0 0 20 0h-3" />
</svg>
normal SVG.

<p>Red SVG:
<svg class="red" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
   <use href="#anchor" />
</svg>
and normal text again. 

<p class="red">
Red text with
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
   <use href="#anchor" />
</svg>
red SVG.
```

Universal selector `*` is rarely optimal solution for any task. Besides introducing potential "footguns" like this one, it can even be slightly detrimental for performance.

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation and efforts for making this too easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

in SVG elements colors must be set by `fill` property.

```css
:root {
  --logo-color : red;
  --text-color : blue;
  }
* {
  color : var(--text-color);
  }
.logo{
  fill  : var(--logo-color);
  } 
svg {
  width  : 150px; 
  height : 150px; 
  }
```

```html
<svg class="logo" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
 fill="none"
 stroke="currentColor"
 stroke-width="2"
 stroke-linecap="round"
 stroke-linejoin="round"
>
   <circle cx="12" cy="5" r="3" />
   <line x1="12" y1="22" x2="12" y2="8" />
   <path d="M5 12H2a10 10 0 0 0 20 0h-3" />
</svg>
```

You can also use  in  **CSS** `stroke : var(--text-color);`
instead of actual svg property `stroke="currentColor"`

```css
:root {
  --logo-color : red;
  --text-color : blue;
  }
svg {
  width           : 150px; 
  height          : 150px;
  fill            : var(--logo-color);
  stroke          : var(--text-color);
  stroke-width    : 2;
  stroke-linecap  : round;
  stroke-linejoin : round;
  }
svg path {
  stroke          : darkgreen;
  }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" >
 <circle cx="12" cy="5" r="3" />
 <line x1="12" y1="22" x2="12" y2="8" />
 <path d="M5 12H2a10 10 0 0 0 20 0h-3" />
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, in my case I just had to use the stroke property instead of color. As you explained it very well in your demos. thank u